# No value given for one or more required parameter error for VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, recursion, common-table-expression, sqldatasource

I have a SQL data table which contains below data.

[image]

In this I need to get the "Component" data which are structured under "Item" and after that each component will be considered as "Item" and recursive CTE comes here. I have executed the below code for this, but I am facing with error. Please help me to sort this out.

```
        revQueryString = "with ReqCTE as (" & _
                      "SELECT Item, Component, qtyper, 0 as lvl FROM STRUCT " & _
                      "where Item = ? " & _
                      "Union all " & _
                      "select Folders.Item, Folders.Component, Folders.qtyper, Child.lvl +1 from ReqCTE as Child " & _
                      "join STRUCT as Folders on Folders.Item = Child.Item); " & _
                      "select * from ReqCTE;"
```

Also I have attached the input and required Output for this task.

Input:

[image]

Required Output:

[image]